# Createing test case for login screen in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I know how to create a test case but how to trigger that case while login information get wrong or any wrong thing falls at login. Please also elaborate what is actually use of test case in our app development. I read some article but still not getting whole concept. Help will appreciated.

Comment: You are giving too little information, please amend your question.

Comment: i just need to know what is actually use of test case and when they trigger while they are already create